# Is it OK to use `* -text diff` in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, newline, line-endings, gitattributes

We have a large collection of files we want to put in a Git repository. Line endings include LF, CRLF, and mixed LF/CRLF. It's important in our context to keep these files exactly as-is, byte-for-byte.

Git likes to store text files with LF line endings. Normally if you have a case that must be CRLF, you should add `.gitattributes` entries to indicate that it should be written to the working directory as CRLF but in our case there are no easy patterns. That is, we can't just say `*.foo eol=crlf` or `/bar/** eol=crlf`.

We thought about using `* binary`, but then we learned that [according to GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings):

> The `binary` setting is also an alias for `-text -diff`.

We had the idea that we could disable Git's line-ending conversion by writing a `gitattributes` containing only:

```
* -text diff
```

and get all the diff/history/merge behaviors of text files, without the line ending conversions.

Are there any downsides would should be aware of with this approach? Does it affect more than just line ending encoding?

Comment: That's fine. You can also just write `* -text` and not mention `diff` and Git will do its usual guessing for whether to be `diff` or `-diff` on those files, but an explicit `diff` will tell it to go ahead and do diffs. (Since—unlike crlf conversion—diff vs -diff doesn't affect the *stored* files, it's not so terribly important to get this one right every time.)